# Accessing laptop's/tablet's hardware like webcam with Cordova from GWT application?

Tags: gwt, cordova

I'm new to Cordova. I have a web application developed in GWT and I'm trying to find out if it is possible to access device's capabilities like laptop's webcam or battery status using Cordova from my web application.

So far I've concluded the answer is "NOP", but someone could provide me with some examples or counterargument.

I found in docs Windows 7+ or Linux are not among the supported platforms:

> Cordova provides a set of uniform JavaScript libraries that can be invoked, with device-specific native backing code for those JavaScript libraries. Cordova is available for the following platforms: iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada, and Symbian

Also, what happens if I run my GWT web application on a tablet browser? Will Cordova plugins work with my current GWT application or I need to redevelop it using gwt-phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md) document, you can use webcam on windows 8.

And if you want to use phonegap in your GWT project, you can do it without any GWT plugins, just use native methods:

```
public native static void getPicture() /*-{
    if ($wnd.cordova) {
        $wnd.navigator.camera.getPicture(function onSuccess(imageURI) {
            $wnd.alert(imageURI);
        }, function onFail(message) {
            $wnd.alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    } else {
        $wnd.alert('PhoneGap does not defined');
    }
}-*/;
```

Comment: OK, I see. So it really depends on the plugin and your settings

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cordova doesn't run inside any web browser, be it on a PC, tablet, or otherwise.

Apache Cordova doesn't support Windows very well(if at all) at present -- but there is a repo with code in, for [Cordova for Windows](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows). Cordova supports Ubuntu (Touch and Desktop) via [Cordova for Ubuntu](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ubuntu), other Linux distros don't appear to be so well supported.

Your GWT app may well work with Cordova with no or minimal plugins or tweaking. It is not possible to be categorical, without you having tested first.